# How to solve dotnet core runtime missing error when sdk is already installed

Tags: linux, .net-core, runtime

I have a dotnet 3.1 console application on centos linux.

The error is:

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.

- No frameworks were found.

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:

- https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=centos.7-x64

I have dotnet sdk installed on server. dotnet --info gives

.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version:   3.1.411
Commit:    d100cdf718

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     centos
OS Version:  7
OS Platform: Linux
RID:         centos.7-x64
Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.411/

Host (useful for support):
Version: 3.1.17
Commit:  3a75b805fa

.NET Core SDKs installed:
3.1.411 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.17 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.17 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue on dotnet 8.0 in my ubuntu server. The point is that when you install and check dotnet dotnet --info, you might found /usr/share such path. You can also use that dotnet runtimes for few days but the runtimes will became missing. In my case mostly in 5-6 days, dotnet runtime got missing. I was so worried as well as wonder at the same time for the issue.

```
The best way to fix the solution is:

sudo apt remove dotnet*
sudo apt remove aspnetcore*
sudo apt remove netstandard*
```

This will delete all your previous dotnet configuration.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-8.0
```

I am using here sdk-8.0 but you can use any of your requirement.